# Stream live images in Android

Tags: android, image, stream, android-videoview

I've an stream source link like this: 
http://210.245.17.188:8090/stream911
This is a list of realtime image source, not a video source (you can open above link in the browser to see what it looks like). Now I want to stream these image to device like streaming video. I've used VideoView to stream this link but it's not worked. How can I solve this?

Comment: The link above does not work!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using VideoView,my sample code is as below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

java class

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare variables
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;

    // Insert your Video URL
    String VideoURL = "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);
        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask

        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoViewActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });

    }

}
```